# Sort Wordpress posts by first content letter

Tags: php, wordpress

Question title completely reflects my issue. I'm build non-profit collection of poems, and want sort them alphabetical. Native Wordpress sorting in this case is unsuitable. Must sort poems by first letter of content, not title.

Excuse me for bad English, please. And thanks everyone who can help me.

Comment: you should delete this question from this generic programming site and post it over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which is the stackoverflow sister site just for wordpress development. you will get more experts looking at it over there. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post content is stored in database in a field without index which is slow for sorting and grouping (requires a full table scan). The more posts you have - the slower it gets and consumes more server resources. This is why it's not a good idea. However, there are some options and I would recommend using tags/categories or custom taxonomy. Create taxonomy terms by letters from A to Z and assign them to your posts (poems). It's an extra click when adding new post but these architecture will give you a lot of flexibility in terms of posts sorting, ordering, searching etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using this solution, but wanted to make process simplier.